# Does "Disarm" need a to hit roll?

Tags: dark-heresy-1e

Dark Heresy page 114 says that, when engaged, you just spend a full action and make an opposed WS check.

There's no to hit/parry roll, right? Can the opponent parry?

Answer (score 1):

**Correct / No**

The opposed WS test is the "attack roll".  Since Disarm is a full action and not just an extension of an attack, that means that there aren't any traditional means to follow up the disarm with another attack. As far as the defender, the WS they oppose with is already a Parry attempt by proxy and would cover their only defense attempt (which they are allowed even if in full charge since it's part of your ability and not their preparation)